# list of zipcodes and cities, excel ark or database?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this list of the Danish zipcodes (available for all online), right now i have it as an excel ark. But been wondering if it would be best to put it in my database instead.

i have this view with both editorfor

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Postnr, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Postnr, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Postnr, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.By, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.By, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.By, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

i would like to use javascript to update by(city), when Postnr blurred. Any good ideas how to do this?

```
999     København C 
1000    København K 
1050    København K 
1051    København K 
1052    København K 
1053    København K 
1054    København K 
1055    København K 
1056    København K 
1057    København K 
1058    København K 
1059    København K 
1060    København K 
1061    København K 
1062    København K 
1063    København K 
1064    København K 
1065    København K
```

Example of how text is in excel

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? What is it you are going to update? Are you assigning zip codes to cities? Is the city information in your database?

Comment: no both zipcodes and cities are in the excel ark, zipcodes are already asigned to each city, (weird thing here in Denmark) all i want it to do is when you enter an Zipcode in the "postnr" a javascript runthrough and find the citys name and put it as @value for by(city) makes sense?

Comment: Yes makes sense.. I'm not familiar with Excel Ark so I don't know how easy it is to read and write too. Normal Excel sheets require an Interop. So I'd simply say, if it is easy to read and write to and from the Ark, then keep your data there. You can do an Ajax post to a controller with the postnr and city to update it.

Comment: not so familiar with Ajax, how would be an example to do it, if i put the zipcode/city in Database.

Comment: I've posted an example as an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested.. here is an example Ajax post.

```
 $(document).on("click","#btnYOURBUTTON", function () {
            var newPostnrValue = $('#postnrTextBoxName').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController")",
                data: newPostnrValue
            });
    });
```

Multiple parameters

```
 $(document).on("click","#btnYOURBUTTON", function () {
            var param1Value= $('#param1Value').val();
            var param2Value= $('#param2Value').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController")",
                data: {paramName1: param1Value, paramName2: param2Value}
            });
    });
```

pramName1 etc... must match the spelling exactly of your controller action method param names.

Or post the whole form. i.e. your view html is wrapped in a form tag.

```
 $(document).on("click","#btnYOURBUTTON", function () {
           var myData = $('#YourFormID').serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController")",
                data: myData,
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
            });
    });
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: oka just  to to clarify,(data:) tag is the parameter for my controllers action?

Comment: Yes correct. I've edited the answer for different scenarios.

Comment: Thanks, i will test out a bit with this, but this was what i was looking for, thank you for the good explanation.